# Subspace test with matrices

Tags: linear-algebra

Looking to see if this subset is a subspace.

$ U = \{A \in M_n\Bbb (R) : A^t = A\}$

My answer:

1) U is not empty: clearly if we let $A = 0$ then $A^t= 0$ so $A^t=A$

2) $A + B$ is in $U$: so if we let $A$ and $B$ be in $U$, and we know that $A^T=A$ and $B^T=B$ then $(A+B)^T=A^T+B^T=A+B$

Also for 3) $(aA^T)=aA^t=aA$ does this T not come on to the scaler because it is just simply a number and you can not get the tranverse of a number?

I am not quite understanding step 2. is $(A+B)^T=A^T+B^T$ a rule in matrices?

Comment: Just check every index. $(A+B)^T_{ij}=(A+B)_{ji}=A_{ji}+B_{ji}=A^T_{ij}+B^T_{ij}=(A^T+B^T)_{ij}$. You can use a similar argument to show that $(cA)^T=cA^T$.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, $A^T+B^T=(A+B)^T$ is always true for $A,B\in M_n(\mathbb{R})$. It follows easily from the definition of transposition:
$$(A^T+B^T)_{i,j}=(A^T)_{i,j}+(B^T)_{i,j}=A_{j,i}+B_{j,i}=(A+B)_{j,i}=((A+B)^T)_{i,j}.$$
You can check that $aA^T=(aA)^T$ in the same way:
$$(aA^T)_{i,j}=a(A^T)_{i,j}=aA_{j,i}=(aA)_{j,i}=((aA)^T)_{i,j}.$$

Comment: I have a edit to my question about $(aA)^T = aA^T$ can you address that?

Comment: thanks for your answer btw